# Way to find value in a date range Excell

Tags: excel-formula

I have Start date + time and End date + time in table 1, then i have a range of dates and values in table 2. what i want is to find the highest value from table 2 that happened in the date range from table 1.
For example in table 1:
start date 12/30/2020 08:03 ; end date 12/31/2020 17:26
in table 2 is:
12/30/2020 08:00             1145
12/30/2020 09:00             2145
12/30/2020 10:00             3912
12/30/2020 08:00             1472
and so on. so in the row of table 1 i want to see the number 3912

Comment: You need the [MAXIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose both of your tables are **structured reference table** as shown below:

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

You can use either of the following formula to return the desired value:

```
=MAX((Table2[Date]>=Table1[@[Start Date]])*(Table2[Date]<=Table1[@[End Date]])*Table2[Value])
```

This one is using **MAXIFS** as suggested by Nicholas Hunter in the comment section:

```
=MAXIFS(Table2[Value],Table2[Date],">="&Table1[@[Start Date]],Table2[Date],"<="&Table1[@[End Date]])
```

[image: Solutions]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table 1 = A1-B10 and table 2 is in D1-10,

try making another column (lets say F1-10) with the following: =IF(And(D1<B1,D1>A1),D1,0)
and in whatever cell you want the highest Date, put =Large(F1-10)

Make sure that the final cell has "Date" format, otherwise it will look like a weird number. if you want to look at the intermediary steps, do the same for F1-10.